# Node.js & Socket.io with multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

From my understanding, a socket.io server manages N connections between itself and N clients via N separate sockets, each with its own ID.

It therefore makes sense that you get two different ID's when opening two tabs.

Consider, however, this minimal example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Stuffy Stuff</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btnA">A</button>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var servercode = require('./server');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    console.log('client ' + socket.id + ' connected');
    servercode.init(io, socket);
});
```

**app.js**

```
;
jQuery(function($) // client-side code
{
    socket = io.connect();

    $(document).on('click', '#btnA', stuff);

    function stuff()
    {
        socket.emit('dostuff', socket.id);
        socket.on('answerstuff', function()
        {
            console.log("Answered");
        });
    }
}($));
```

**server.js**

```
// Server-side

var io;
var socket;

exports.init = function(sio, sock)
{
    io = sio;
    socket = sock;

    socket.on('dostuff', doStuff);
};

function doStuff(idd)
{
    console.log('who is asking: ' + idd);
    console.log('who am I answering to: ' + socket.id);  
    console.log(socket.id);
    socket.emit('answerstuff');
}
```

Now say I fire up `node index.js` and then open two instances of `localhost:8080`; let's call them A and B. If I press the button on A's instance, the 'dostuff' message is emitted, it's caught by the server, *but the socket it answers to is the one relative to B's instance*, not A's. In general, it answers to the most recent instance. Why is it so?

**EDIT: explanation**
As I've finally grasped the nature of my mistake I thought I could help whoever runs into a similar issue.

Let's take our sample workflow: A connects, B connects, A presses button.

1. `server.init(io, socket A)` gets called
2. `init(socket A)` attaches the `dostuff` event, with callback function `doStuff`, to socket A
3. B connects... `init` attaches `dostuff` to socket B
4. Client A presses button, thus A emits `dostuff` passing socket A's id
5. `doStuff(idd)` is executed, but its definition contains a reference to a variable (`socket`) not defined within the function's scope, therefore it has to navigate its parent scopes
6. Such reference is found: it's `socket = sock` (if we omit `var`, the declaration 'bubbles up' in scope until it finds a variable with such a name. Had we written `var socket = sock` INSIDE `init`, the function couldn't have found any such variable)

   7. But `socket` points to socket B thanks to B connecting and `init` being executed again. Therefore, the function only knows socket B.

In order to solve this issue we need to employ *closures*: functions that encapsulate the state of the world at the moment of their definition. In other words, a closure is an object containing the function definition AND the value of the variables not in the function scope but referenced by it.

As illustrated in the solution given by JagsSparrow, there are two ways of dealing with this issue and both involve creating a closure:

**1. Use the `function.bind(thisArg, args)` function**

The `bind()` function returns the function 'A' it's called upon where `this` is bound to `thisArg` (where it would normally point to the object calling A) and instantiates whatever arguments are specified in `args`.

In our case we don't need `this` as it's never mentioned in the `doStuff()` function, but we do need it to remember whose socket is the one mentioned in the arguments. We can do this by writing

```
doStuff.bind(null, socket)
```

This expression returns an object that is the `doStuff()` function where, in its context, `this` equals `null` (we could've written `doStuff.bind(this, socket)`: in that case, `this` equals `init`) and its first argument, `socket`, is bound to `socket`. Therefore,

```
socket.on('dostuff', doStuff.bind(this,socket));
```

tells socket A to fire up `doStuff` (which *contains a reference to socket A*) when `dostuff` happens. Same with socket B and any other socket.

**2. Use a nested function**

We simply move the definition of `function doStuff(idd)` inside `socket.on()`:

```
socket.on('dostuff', function doStuff(idd)
{
    console.log('who is asking: ' + idd);
    console.log('who am I answering to: ' + socket.id);  
    console.log(socket.id);
    socket.emit('answerstuff');
});
```

This way, again, the socket is bound to a function that contains (by virtue of the closure) the definition of whichever socket is performing this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `server.js` you declared `var socket;` which is **local of the server.js module (module scope)**,

So this variable gets assigned to different client each time its get connected

1. When client A get connected `socket` is of client A.
2. When client B get connected `socket` is of client B.

So, Don't make `socket` variable local to server.js module

**Solution 1 :** 
**server.js**

```
var io;
//var socket;

exports.init = function(sio, sock)
{
    io = sio;
    socket = sock;

    socket.on('dostuff', doStuff.bind(this,socket));
};

function doStuff(socket,idd)
{
    console.log('who is asking: ' + idd);
    console.log('who am I answering to: ' + socket.id);  
    console.log(socket.id);
    socket.emit('answerstuff');
}
```

**Solution 2 :** 
**server.js**

```
var io;
//var socket;

exports.init = function(sio, sock)
{
    io = sio;
    var socket = sock;

    socket.on('dostuff', function doStuff(idd)
    {
        console.log('who is asking: ' + idd);
        console.log('who am I answering to: ' + socket.id);  
        console.log(socket.id);
        socket.emit('answerstuff');
    });
};
```

Comment: Your code works correctly, but the explanation you give is somewhat confusing. My understanding is that you create a closure where the doStuff() function "remembers" which socket it's referencing. In fact, your code works even if you leave `var socket` uncommented.

Comment: Yes, its closure. if you uncomment it will still take local variable, as its in local scope, but as you know, now `module scope` socket is of no use so commented it.